# Campos bloqueados no IE

Tags: html5, asp, internet-explorer, materialize

Boa tarde.

Tenho um formulário em que os campos no IE ficam bloqueados, sendo acessíveis apenas com o uso da tecla TAB, em outros navegadores não ocorre o problema.
Não é possível executar ação nenhuma, selecionar elemento nenhum da página com o mouse.

O formulário é feito utilizando html, asp e materializecss.

O que pode estar causando o erro? O que devo estudar a respeito?

Obrigado.

[image: Formulário]

Comment: Olá colega, tem como postar seu código HTML e CSS para que possamos dar uma olhada?

Comment: Coloque o código para a gente analisar, Jean